# Xamarin - cambie el target framework de Android 9 (api28) a Android 10 (api29) y el apk generado no se instala en el movil

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2019, sdk

llevo una semana con este problema, por un aviso de Google de que las nuevas apps no deben tener un targetsdk inferior a 29 cambie mi proyecto de 28 a 29 y luego de generar el apk firmado y pasarlo al móvil, no consigo instalarlo, con la version 28 todo funcionaba correctamente.
Estoy usando VS2019 - Xamarin - Syncfusion controls.
Hice el cambio también a la api 30, pero el resultado es el mismo.
Por favor, alguien puede darme alguna posible solución?
Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tuve un problema similar y lo solucione practiacmente creando un proyecto nuevo con la api anterior. Lo tuve que mudar archivo por archivo.

Comment: Hola, cuando indicás que hiciste un proyecto nuevo con la api anterior, sería que lo creaste nuevamente en la api28 y la pasaste a api29? Gracias!

Comment: Es que habia un problema de permisos en la api nueva que puse y me toco dejar todo en la api anterior, en este caso para ti seria dejar todo en la api28 si ya te sirve ahi, a veces los paquetes de permisos de Xamarin tienen algunos problemas al actualizar de api.

Answer (score 1):

finalmente logré solucionar el problema, en base al logcat del emulador cuando trataba de instalar el apk generado por VS2019, arrojó dos errores en forma separada

a) NativeLibraryHelper  Library 'libmono-btls-shared.so' is not page-aligned - will not be able to open it directly from apk.
NativeHelper    Failure copying native libraries [errorCode=-2]
PackageInstallerSession Commit of session 615863848 failed: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-2

No se podía acceder a la librería por que el apk no estaba alineado

b) InstallFailed Installation status code: 1

Se produce por que la apk no estaba firmada

Saludos!